# Calling private methods

Tags: javascript

I'm following this [blog](http://rog.ie/blog/javascript-classes) and playing with code.

```
function MyClass() {
  var self = this;
  var privateVar = 'My Private Variable';
  this.publicVar = 'My Public Variable';
  var privateFunction = function () {
    self.publicVar += ' Modified By A Private Fucntion';
    alert(self.publicVar);
  };
  privateFunction(); //1:  why this code not working. kindly give the reason for this.
}
```

How might i can call `privateFunction` ?? 
Output that i am looking for  // "My Private Variable Modified By A Private Fucntion"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work. Most likely you are not instantiating MyClass anywhere.

```
function MyClass() {
var self = this;
var privateVar = 'My Private Variable';
this.publicVar = 'My Public Variable';
var privateFunction = function () {
  self.publicVar += ' Modified By A Private Fucntion';
  alert(self.publicVar);
};
privateFunction(); // why this code not working..
};
new MyClass(); //Run MyClass, triggering all code.
```